# Sort files into folders based on first two digits of filename?

Tags: finder, applescript, automator, file, file-transfer

I constantly get hundreds of .pdf files I would like sorted into folders based on the filename.

The filenames are made up of a couple elements, although only the first string of letters and the first two digits are relevant. The letters represent the customer code and the digits represent the year.

Here's two examples:

- **TX20**4190_100_GR.pdf. **TX** is the customer code and **20** represents 2020.
- **SFLYMK22**0921_CR2050_BLKHTH.pdf. **SFLYMK** is the customer code and **22** represents 2022.

The PDFs start off as direct siblings to the year folders. I need these PDFs to go inside the correct year folder and then the correct customer folder. So for example, TX204190_100_GR.pdf would need to go inside *2020* and then go inside the *TX* folder. The folders will all already exist.

[Before Sorting Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IkQV.jpg)

[After Sorting Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyaHh.jpg)

I'm struggling to find a way to select only the customer code (which can be anywhere from 2 to 8 characters) and the following two digits with automator so that I can properly move the files. I'd assume it requires some kind of regex solution, but I don't know where to even begin or even if that's possible using only Automator. Any advice or help with this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do the, e.g., **TX** and **SFLYMK** _folders_ already exist and if so where, and if not, where should they be created? Do the **year** _folders_ already exist?

Comment: Did something similar years ago, but used the 8 first characters for every name - that way the string length was known. You have a varying length with no defined separator. I would have started with left() in excel but not sure.

Comment: @user3439894 All folders already exist. The .pdf files that need to be sorted would be initially located in a parent folder which also has the year folders as siblings to the .pdfs.

Comment: If you know all the customer codes then they don’t have to be found - you can match them. Use a loop to go through the customer codes one by one then an inner loop for the year.

Comment: RE: "The .pdf files that need to be sorted would be initially located in a parent folder which also has the year folders as siblings to the .pdfs." --  Are you saying that the e.g. **TX204190_100_GR.pdf** is already in the **TX** _folder_ and just needs to be moved into its **2020** _folder_?

Comment: @user3439894 For clarification, there's a big "Orders" folder which contains the 2022, 2021, 2020, 2019 folders. The file is on the same level of those year folders. TX204190_100_GR.pdf needs to  first go inside the 2020 folder and then it needs to go inside the TX folder. Here's a visual [link](https://imgur.com/D4Y5rbl)

Comment: NicholasGFX, I have modified the original _code_ in the _regex_ test, changing `$f` to `${f##*/}` so it's testing against just the _filename_, as it's a better way to test even though under the current circumstances the original test was valid. I've also added an additional _example_ **Automator** _workflow_. and its _example_ **shell script** _code_ is different than the original _example_ **shell script** _code_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an *example* **Automator** *workflow* that you might find helpful.

*Example* **shell script** *code* for the **Run Shell Script** *action*:

```bash
d="$HOME/Documents/Orders"

for f in "$@"; do
    if [[ ${f##*/} =~ ([[:alpha:]]{2,8})([[:digit:]]{2})(.*) ]]; then
        c="$match[1]"
        y="$match[2]"
        [ ! -d "$d/20$y/$c/" ] && mkdir -p "$d/20$y/$c/"
        mv -n "$f" "$d/20$y/$c/"
    fi
done
```

**Notes:**

Change the *value* of `d` to the *fully qualified pathname* of the, e.g. **Orders** *directory*.

In this *example* **Automator** *workflow* the settings for the **Run Shell Script** *action* are: **Shell: [/bin/zsh]** and **Pass input: [as arguments]**.

---

[image]

---

**Notes:**

As I said, "Here is an *example* **Automator** *workflow* ..." and it is just that, an *example*. The main part is the *shell script code* in **Run Shell Script** *action*, as it does the real work! So, whichever way you want the *workflow* to pass a *list* of qualifying *files* to the **Run Shell Script** *action*, even if modifying the *code* as necessary based on how you want the *files* passed, you should be in business. Any *files* not matching the *regex* are ignored.

Addressing a comment, also note that while `mkdir -p "$d/20$y/$c/"` does not explicitly need to be tested for, nonetheless, it is a coding force of habit if you will, used in similar paradigms. You can omit the `[ ! -d "$d/20$y/$c/" ] &&` portion of that *command* if you so choose. However, that said, I'd leave it as `[ ! -d "$d/20$y/$c/" ] &&` uses the `zsh` *shell built-in command* for `[` and testing for it existence incurs far less overhead than needlessly executing the `mkdir` *command* every time when the target *directory* already exists!

---

### A different **Automator** *workflow*

As an example, the **Automator** *workflow* could consist of just the **Run Shell Script** *action* with the following *example* **shell script** *code*:

```bash
d="$HOME/Documents/Orders"

cd "$d" || exit

[ -z "$(ls *.[pP][dD][fF])" ] && exit

for f in *.[pP][dD][fF]; do
    if [[ $f =~ ([[:alpha:]]{2,8})([[:digit:]]{2})(.*) ]]; then
        c="$match[1]"
        y="$match[2]"
        [ ! -d "$d/20$y/$c/" ] && mkdir -p "$d/20$y/$c/"
        mv -n "$f" "$d/20$y/$c/"
    fi
done
```

**Notes:**

Change the *value* of `d` to the *fully qualified pathname* of the, e.g. **Orders** *directory*.

In this *example* **Automator** *workflow* the settings for the **Run Shell Script** *action* are: **Shell: [/bin/zsh]** and **Pass input: [to stdin]**.

[image]

---

### What the *example* **shell script** *code* does:

- `d="$HOME/Documents/Orders"` -- Sets the *value* of the `d` *variable* to the target location of the *files* to be processed.
- `cd "$d" || exit` -- Changes directory to the target *directory* or exits the *script*.
- `[ -z "$(ls *.[pP][dD][fF])" ] && exit` -- Test for the existence of the target **PDF** *files* and exits the *script* if none exist at the target location. This test is necessary to avoid an error in the `for` *loop* to keep the **Automator** *workflow* from throwing an *error* if run and no target **PDF** *files* exists.
- `for f in *.[pP][dD][fF]; do` -- For each target **PDF** *file* do something.
- `if [[ $f =~ ([[:alpha:]]{2,8})([[:digit:]]{2})(.*) ]]; then` -- If the target *file* matches the *regex*, then do something.
- `c="$match[1]"` -- Sets the *value* of the `c` *variable* to the **Customer Code**. The *value* of the first **Capturing Group** of the *regex*.
- `y="$match[2]"` --  Sets the *value* of the `y` *variable* to the **Year**. The *value* of the second **Capturing Group** of the *regex*.
- `[ ! -d "$d/20$y/$c/" ] && mkdir -p "$d/20$y/$c/"` -- If the target *directory* doesn't exist, then create it.
- `mv -n "$f" "$d/20$y/$c/"` -- Move the target *file* to the target *directory*.
- `fi` -- Closes the `if` *statement block*.
- `done` -- Closes the `do` *loop*.

**Explanation of the Regex:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Omg, incredible!! It even makes the correct folders if they don't already exist, which does happen from time to time with new customers. You're a saint!

Comment: @NicholasGFX, As I said "Here is an _example_ **Automator** _workflow_ ..." and it is just that, an _example_. The main part is the _shell script code_ in **Run Shell Script** _action_, (and its settings), as it does the real work!. So, whichever way you want the _workflow_ to pass a _list_ of qualifying _files_ to the **Run Shell Script** _action_, you should be in business. Any _files_ not matching the _regex_ are ignored, and of course I coded it to make the _directory_ if it didn't already exist as it's the prudent thing to do.

Comment: +1 … Comment on the mkdir line: `mkdir -p` does nothing if the directory already exists, so the preceding test is not strictly needed.  Also, if you want to skip the Automator overhead, just `cd "$HOME/Documents/Orders"; ls _glob_ | _script_` (where "glob" is a pattern to skip unwanted files and script is the shell script above, with or without the first line)

Comment: @WGroleau, RE: "mkdir -p does nothing if the directory already exists, so the preceding test is not strictly needed." -- True it's not strictly needed, it's just a coding force of habit if you will, used in similar paradigms. RE: "if you want to skip the Automator overhead..." -- These are exactly some of the reasons why I've explicitly stated "_example_ **Automator** _workflow_", which means to be used as an _example_, not necessarily verbatim! Part of the issue is if you look at the comments to the OP and its edit history, I started this when first posted and didn't refine it before posting!

Comment: I get it.  Just adding additional info for OP.

Comment: @user3439894 Sorry about that. I did make several edits since as a few questions came in, it became more evident which aspects of the problem I wasn't communicating very well. Anyway, now I have a decent starting point I can build off of. I understand most of what that script is doing, but with my current knowledge, there's not a chance I would have been able to write that from scratch without it taking me at least a few days of trial/error. Do you have any recommendations on where I should look if I wanted to learn to do more of this type of automation myself?

Comment: @NicholasGFX, RE: "Do you have any recommendations on where I should look if I wanted to learn to do more of this type of automation myself?" -- If you are referring to _shell scripting_, then IMO you need to read the full manual for the _shell_ you are using. **macOS** switched to the **Z Shell** (`zsh`), so have a look at [ZSH Documentation](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/) to download a **PDF** copy, and look at the [Release Notes](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/releases.html). Also, https://stackoverflow.com/ is a great resource, as well as here. Another good resource is: https://regex101.com

Comment: @NicholasGFX, Have a look at my updated answer. I have modified some of the _code_ and have added a **What the example shell script code does:** _section_ to help you understand in general what the _example_ **shell script** _code_ is doing. I've also added some screen shots from https://regex101.com/ to explain the _regex_.  This added info covers specifically the second **Automator** _workflow_ and is a bit different than the first **Automator** _workflow_. However, most is applicable to both. If you have any specific questions, let me know.